# Instanceof Collection not Acting as Expected

Tags: java, spring, validation, collections

I'm implementing some Spring Framework validation through implementing the Validator interface. I want to *support* my DTO object, a Long (for primary key validation), and a Collection so that I don't need to call the Invoke Validation numerous times in my controller methods

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.validation.Validator#supports(java.lang.Class)
 */
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

    Class<?>[] supportedClasses = {

            UserDTO.class,
            Collection.class,
            Long.class
    };
    for(Class<?> c : supportedClasses){
        if(clazz.equals(c)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.validation.Validator#validate(java.lang.Object, org.springframework.validation.Errors)
 */
@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

    if(target instanceof Collection<?>){
        Iterator<?> i = ((Collection<?>) target).iterator();

        while(i.hasNext()){
            validate(i.next(), errors);
        }

        return;
    }
```

In my controller when I am invoking the Validation I am passing an ArrayList, but receiving a IllegalArgumentException (Validator class does not support ArrayList). This *should* work right? Because ArrayList is-a Collection therefore (ArrayList instanceof Collection) should return true.

If this logic is not correct please let me know. This is really stressing me out. Also, please do not mention the simple javax validation in the models e.g.

```
// ---- Bean Class

@NotNull
private String attribute;

// ...
```

The reason is because I was doing this previously, but required to change it because the *standards* I should be using requires this framework.

Comment: If your error message is `Validator class does not support...`, it's probably because of the `support()` method.  And that method uses `equals` to check the classes, not `instanceof`.  So it never gets to the statement that uses `instanceof`.  Try [Class.isInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your support method like this

```
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

    Class<?>[] supportedClasses = {

            UserDTO.class,
            Collection.class,
            Long.class
    };
    for(Class<?> c : supportedClasses){
        if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(clazz)(c)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Explanation**

supports method determines whether or not an instance is of a class can be validated by this validator or not.

Correct way of implementing it is to use `Class.isAssignable`

```
Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(ArrayList.class); // Returns true
```

If you use `class.equals` following statement will return false

```
Collection.class.equals(ArrayList.class) // Returns false
```